# Write if else statements

Tags: r

I am trying to do an outlier treatment in one of my data frame using the following logic. However its either giving NA's in the new column or updating it as FALSE. Any thoughts, comments would be appreciated.

```
ar_model1$new_actuals <- as.numeric(ifelse(
    (ar_model1$sub_count_all >= 2000 & ar_model1$weekday == 1),
    ar_model1$new_actuals == 2000,
    ar_model1$new_actuals == ar_model1$sub_count_all))
```

Comment: Are you trying to make `new_actuals` equal to 2000 under the condition and equal to `sub_count_all` otherwise? If so, try `ar_model1$new_actuals <- as.numeric(
        ifelse(
            (ar_model1$sub_count_all >= 2000 & ar_model1$weekday == 1), 
            2000, 
            ar_model1$sub_count_all)
    )`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using '==' comparison. Assuming what you are looking at is, if the cond satisfies you want 2000 else value from sub_count_all. Then the following code should work.

```
 ar_model1$new_actuals <- as.numeric(ifelse(
(ar_model1$sub_count_all >= 2000 & ar_model1$weekday ==1),
 2000,ar_model1$sub_count_all))
```

Comment: Thanks zx8754 & Jil Jung Juk, Yes I get the problem. I was trying to do it the Excel way. I get your answer and it makes sense.